# Why Am I getting an error when I add the number parameter to my WP_User_Query?

Tags: pagination, sql, wp-user-query

I have a custom `WP_Users_Query` that I have been using on a site.

It has worked fine for a while. I went to add some pagination to the query using the `number` parameter [as per the docs here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Pagination_Parameters). But for some reason, when I add that parameter I get an SQL error, unless I set it to `-1` where it returns everything.

Here is my code that works:

```
$user_fields = array( 'ID', 'display_name', 'user_email' );
$args = array(
    'role__in' => array('Subcriber', 'Editor'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'list_in_directory',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ),
    'fields' => $user_fields,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
); // End Args

if ($args){
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
}
```

If I add the line:`'number' => '2'` to my args array (I have tried it both as a string and an integer, both with the same result) I get this error in my log:

> WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-2, 2' at line 15 for query
>   `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.ID,wp_users.display_name,wp_users.user_email FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON ( wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id )  INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_users.ID = mt1.user_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND (
>     (
>       (
>         ( wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'list_in_directory' AND wp_usermeta.meta_value = '1' )
>       )
>       AND
>       (
>         (
>           ( mt1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%\"Subcriber\"%' )
>           OR
>           ( mt1.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND mt1.meta_value LIKE '%\"Editor\"%' )
>         )
>       )
>     )
>   ) ORDER BY user_login ASC LIMIT -2, 2 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/pand/page-templates/membership-directory.php'), WP_User_Query->__construct, WP_User_Query->query`

Also, I have tried using different numbers in place of 2 all with the same result. The only time I don't get the error is if I set it to -1. Then it works just fine(but no pagination).

I'm scratching my head on this one so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error. Here's what I think is happening.

'number' defines the number of users per page, and 'paged' tell the query which page to return.

For example:

```
$args = array('number' => 2, 'paged' => 2)
```

will return the second page at 2 per page.

If you don't have a query string set, you'll get an error because it's trying to show 2 users from a page that is undefined.

The solution is to leave out the 'paged' parameter and let it start on page 1 (the default).

My experience ends here with regard to how to implement pagination, but it looks as if it's a function of the 'offset' parameter like:

```
'offset' => get_query_var($paged) * $number
```

(assuming the query var exists)

Comment: It seems that the `paged` argument and the `get_query_var` is what is causing the error. I'm still working on why and what the solution is. Thanks for the help pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out what my issue was. The issue was with the `paged` argument. I think it was because I was checking for it but in the event it wasn't found it was causing issues. So here is the code I have now that is working.

```
$user_fields = array( 'ID', 'display_name', 'user_email' );
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'number' => '1',
    'role__in' => array('Subcriber', 'Editor'),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'list_in_directory',
            'value' => 1,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
    ),
    'fields' => $user_fields,
    'paged' => $paged
); //End Args
if ($args){
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
}
```

You will notice on the second line I am checking for the `paged` query var and setting it to 1 if it's not found. That seems to have fixed the SQL error.